# How do I stop Spring Data Elasticsearch sending query_binary queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I would like to see what queries Spring Data Elasticsearch actually sends to Elasticsearch (especially when they go wrong) but I find this in the log:

```
[profiles][0]: from[0],size[11]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":11,"query_binary":"eyJxdWVyeSI6eyJxdWVyeV9zdHJpbmciOnsicXVlcnkiOiJCYXMifX19fQ=="}]]
...
QueryParsingException: [profiles] No query registered for [query]
```

Seems like Spring-Data's Elasticsearch integration crafts a binary-query. For debugging I would thing it would be useful to see the original query instead.

Comment: I have also not found a solution for this, except creating custom repositories and using the native query builder.